# How to wait till the scrolling bar will disappear on a loading of a webpage in selenium?

Tags: javascript, json, selenium, loader

I am facing an issue with the page loader while automating a web application.
While loading every page the scrolling bar is receiving the click for all the Web elements. How to wait till that scrolling bar disappear ?.

Please suggest your answer.

[image]

Comment: if you feel any answer is helpful to you then don't forget to `accept` it by click tick mark OR still having query then ask by comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate that loader and put the `ExplicitWait` untill it get invisible and then perform the actions on other elements

```
WebElement loader = driver.findElement(By.id("loader_id"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(loader));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for javaScripts is load on the page or not for that you need to using javascript command in ur scripts like this

```
JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        boolean loadProcess=(Long)js.executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0; 
        while((loadProcess==false)){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                loadProcess=(Long)js.executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0;
                logger.info("loadProcess  : "+loadProcess);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.info("waitForJStoLoad error "+e.getMessage());
            }   }
```